Ansible-playbook cannot read inventory file hosts.yaml when run inside Github Actions
I'm doing a migration from Jenkins into Github actions, and a lot of the automations I'm running a re using ansible playbooks. The ansible needs an inventory file to determine hosts and vars under them. However, when attempting to run said ansible automation in github actions, I get the following error:
 Warning: :  * Failed to parse /__w/aws-infra/aws-
infra/inventories/hosts.yaml with auto plugin: no root 'plugin' key found,
'/__w/aws-infra/aws-infra/inventories/hosts.yaml' is not a
valid YAML inventory plugin config file
Warning: :  * Failed to parse /__w/aws-infra/aws-
infra/inventories/hosts.yaml with yaml plugin: We were unable to read either as
JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Expecting property
name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 25 (char 24)  Syntax Error while
loading YAML.   did not find expected ',' or '}'  The error appears to be in
'<string>': line 2, column 40, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on
the exact syntax problem.
Warning: :  * Failed to parse /__w/aws-infra/aws-
infra/inventories/hosts.yaml with ini plugin: We were unable to read either as
JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Expecting property
name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 25 (char 24)  Syntax Error while
loading YAML.   did not find expected ',' or '}'  The error appears to be in
'<string>': line 2, column 40, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on
the exact syntax problem.
Warning: : Unable to parse /__w/aws-infra/aws-
infra/inventories/hosts.yaml as an inventory source
Warning: : No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 25 (char 24)

My step inside the pipeline goes as follows:
- name: run ansible
  run: |
    ansible-playbook -i ./inventories/hosts.yaml \
    ./create_cluster.yaml

Any help on the topic is much appriciated. If I had to guess at this point, it's failing because some permission thing inside the container. I'm running this on my custom ubuntu-based dockerfile that's build into ghcr and pulled at the beginning of the pipeline. The image contains everything that was used for running this inside Jenkins.
What has been tried so far:

Bumped ancient ansible version to latest
Run the 'hosts.yaml' trough yamllint, ansible-lint
Run ansible-inventory --graph inside gha with success
Raised pipeline permissions to write-all
Tried different paths such as ${{ github.workspace }}/, ./ and simple path for the inventory file.
Exhausted a lot of stackoverflow threads and google results.

Expected result: ansible reads inventory and starts running as normal.
EDIT:
To answer the comments, the contents of the file are in the following format (as specified here). I have the 'all' as the first since I'm not using a separate ansible config file.
all:
  children:
    development:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:
    other-category:
      hosts:
        host1:
        host2:

When this is run inside github actions, it fails with the previously mentioned error message. While being clear, the error really points nowhere. I have tried with converted json with the same results.
Versions:
Ansible-collections:8.6.0
Ansible-core: 2.16.6
Ansible: 9.5.1
Python3, etc. are the latest when installing with ubuntu:22.04.

We were unable to read either as
JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Expecting property
name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 25 (char 24)  Syntax Error while
loading YAML.   did not find expected ',' or '}'  The error appears to be in
'': line 2, column 40, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on
the exact syntax problem. >> seems a pretty clear error message to me. Since you are not showing the content of the said inventory, there is nothing more we can possibly tell you on it here.

Worth reading: [mre]

Sorry about that. I added a sample inventory file contents here, and tested it on my runner. The results were the same as with the larger file. This in my honest opinion, means the file is formatted correctly and the error message is rather strange. You may attempt running this trough yamllint and ansible-lint to verify my findings. Please remember to add a newline at the bottom of the document. I'm not certain the formatting got that right here.

Did you try simply printing (cat) the file from your pipeline? That might give you a bit more clue on what is going on...

Yes, it was the first thing I did. The file prints perfectly. At this point, I think the dockerfile or ansible itself must be the culprit. If I run the same inventory file locally ansible can read it.

I managed to solve the issue. Turns out, inside github actions if you want to pass json as  a command line argument you will have to remove any backslashes. They get interpreted as a part of the json. Better practice would be to compile the json file beforehand.
